# Mimic layout of paracolumned document in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, paracol

I have an unusual document layout where two sections about closely related subjects are set side-by-side. I would like the sections and subsections to be displayed in the same parallel way in the table of contents, like so:
[image: Desired table of contents]

(I know the section numbering repeats, but that I can fix and isn't really part of the question.)

This is not what my table of contents currently looks like. I had thought I could get what I wanted by redefining `\switchcolumn` to, when it is expanded, also write a `\switchcolumn` to the TOC. This is the only difference between the `Paracol` environment used in the MWE and the normal `paracol`

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{kantlipsum,hyperref,paracol}
    \makeatletter
     \def\switchcolumn@i[#1]{
        \@ifstar{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\switchcolumn[#1]*}\oldswitchcolumn[#1]}
                   {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\switchcolumn[#1]}\oldswitchcolumn[#1]}
     }
     \newcommand\switchcolumn@ii{
        \@ifstar{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\switchcolumn*}\oldswitchcolumn}
                   {\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\switchcolumn}\oldswitchcolumn}
     }
    \newenvironment{Paracol}[1]{%
        \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\begin{paracol}{#1}}
        \begin{paracol}{#1}
        \let\oldswitchcolumn\switchcolumn
        \def\switchcolumn{\kernel@ifnextchar[{\switchcolumn@i}{\switchcolumn@ii}}
    }
    {    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\end{paracol}}
        \end{paracol}
    }
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \begin{Paracol}{2}
        \begin{column*}
          \section{Trees}
          \subsection{Silviculture of the Foo Tree} 
          \subsubsection{Habitat} \kant[1-2]
          \subsubsection{Uses} \kant[3]
          \subsubsection{Growth} \kant[4-5]
        \end{column*}

        \begin{column}
          \section{Pests}
          \subsection{Pests of the Foo Tree} 
          \subsubsection{Rats} \kant[1-2]
          \subsubsection{Cats} \kant[3]
          \subsubsection{Hats} \kant[4] 
        \end{column}

        \begin{column*}
          \subsection{Silviculture of the Bar Tree} 
        \end{column*}

        \begin{column}
          \subsection{Pests of the Bar Tree} 
        \end{column}
        \begin{column*}Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
          \subsubsection{Habitat} \kant[5]
          \subsubsection{Uses} \kant[6]
       \end{column*}
        %An image spanning the width of the page 
       \begin{nthcolumn}{0}%Continuation of bar tree silvics
           \subsubsection{Growth} \kant[7]
        \end{nthcolumn}

        \begin{column} Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
          \subsubsection{Pigs} \kant[6]
          \subsubsection{Wigs} \kant[7]
        \end{column}

    \end{Paracol}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I do not think the `\switchcolumn`s are not expanded in the order I expected, resulting in the following, messy TOC.

```
\begin {paracol}{2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Trees}{1}{section.1}
%Many more \contentslines from sections in both columns.
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.1.3}Hats}{3}{subsubsection.1.1.3}
\switchcolumn *
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2}Pests of the Bar Tree}{3}{subsection.1.2}
\switchcolumn *
\switchcolumn 
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.2}Silviculture of the Bar Tree}{4}{subsection.1.2}
\switchcolumn 
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.2.1}Pigs}{4}{subsubsection.1.2.1}
%More \contentslines
\end {paracol}
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.2.2}Uses}{6}{subsubsection.1.2.2}
\switchcolumn [0]
\contentsline {subsubsection}{\numberline {1.2.3}Growth}{6}{subsubsection.1.2.3}
\switchcolumn
```

I'm not really sure how to fix this. If I wanted the contents to align only at the `\section` entries in the TOC I could redefine `\addtocontents` to add the TOC commands to a `\leftcontents` and `\rightcontents` macro and then use those to add the contents at the very end. But since I want them aligned at the subsection level, this would produce something like

```
    \begin{paracol}{2}
        \begin{column}\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Trees}{1}{section.1}\end{column}
        \begin{column}\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Silviculture of the Foo Tree}{1}{subsection.1.1}\end{column}
    %etc.
   \begin{column*}\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Pests}{1}{section.1}\end{column*}
        \begin{column*}\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Pests of the Foo Tree}{1}{subsection.1.1}\end{column*} 
    \end{paracol}
```

Which would still come out wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can achieve something with package [tableof](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tableof).

For some reason I had to comment out all uses of `kantlipsum` in the example, as this had a strange influence on the mixture `paracol+tableof` (which I did not try to understand).

In the code below you could patch `column` and `column*` environments to have the `\TAGLEFT` and `\TAGRIGHT` automatically inserted.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,hyperref,paracol}
\usepackage{tableof}
\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}% see tableof doc, section 2.5

\def\TAGLEFT{\toftagstop{right}\toftagstart{left}}
\def\TAGRIGHT{\toftagstop{left}\toftagstart{right}}
\def\TAGLEFTRIGHT{\toftagstart{left}\toftagstart{right}}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{column*}
    \tableof{left}
  \end{column*}
  \begin{column}
    \tableof{right}
  \end{column}
\end{paracol}

% \tablenotof{left,right}

\begin{paracol}{2}

    \begin{column*}
\TAGLEFT
      \section{Trees}
      \subsection{Silviculture of the Foo Tree} 
      \subsubsection{Habitat} %\kant[1-2]
      \subsubsection{Uses}    %\kant[3]
      \subsubsection{Growth}  %\kant[4-5]
    \end{column*}

    \begin{column}
\TAGRIGHT
      \section{Pests}
      \subsection{Pests of the Foo Tree} 
      \subsubsection{Rats} %\kant[1-2]
      \subsubsection{Cats} %\kant[3]
      \subsubsection{Hats} %\kant[4] 
    \end{column}

    \begin{column*}
\TAGLEFT
      \subsection{Silviculture of the Bar Tree} 
    \end{column*}

    \begin{column}
\TAGRIGHT      \subsection{Pests of the Bar Tree} 
    \end{column}

\begin{column*}
\TAGLEFT
Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
  \subsubsection{Habitat} %\kant[5]
  \subsubsection{Uses}    %\kant[6]
\end{column*}

%An image spanning the width of the page 
\begin{nthcolumn}{0}%Continuation of bar tree silvics
\TAGLEFT
   \subsubsection{Growth} %\kant[7]
\end{nthcolumn}

\begin{column} Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
\TAGRIGHT
  \subsubsection{Pigs} %\kant[6]
  \subsubsection{Wigs} %\kant[7]
\end{column}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

The parallelism of the two TOCs will continue only if they have the same number of sections, subsections, etc...

> [image: Blockquote]